# Seamless scaling of website header on the iphone.

Tags: iphone, html, css

I have a website (http://ukchina-trading.com/) with the following header:

**HTML**

```
        <div class='leftImage'>
            <img src='image/unionjack.png'>
        </div>
        <div class='title'>
            <h1>J Plus Trading</h1>
            <h2>Briding the gap between China and the UK</h2>
        </div>
        <div class='rightImage'>
            <img src='image/chinawings.png'>
        </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.title h1 {
    font-family: 'Droid Serif', Georgia, Times, serif;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 68px;
    line-height: 65px;
    padding-top: 60px;
    margin-bottom: 80px;
}

.title h2 {
    font-family: 'Droid Serif', Georgia, Times, serif;
    text-align: center;
    position:relative;
    top:-88px;
    left:3px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #FF3300;
}
.rightImage {
    position:absolute;
    right: 150px;
    top: 2px;
}

.leftImage {
    position:absolute;
    left: 150px;
    top: 2px;
}
```

When the website is view on a computer the header is fine, but when viewed on the iphone screen the images are pushed over the title, hiding it.

What is the best way to redo the header to stop this?

Comment: If you add a `position:relative` to the `.title` div, and give it a higher `z-index`, atleast the title won't hide ;)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest the best thing to do would be to bring the flags inside the 900px width of the website.

Keep them to the left and right of the "J Plus Trading" text but just use floats rather than absolute positioning.

Answer (score 0):

your problem is the absolute positioning you are using, as this causes the images to be in the same position regardless of anything else on the page. instead of absolute try using float:left; and float:right on your left and right images, and this way the text will not be pushed over it. you may have to create extra containing divs with margins or padding so that the images are positioned how you want them